# How to get 3D coordinates (XYZ) of the sun given Azimuth and altitude?

Tags: node.js

i'm creating a simple program that will simulate sunlight at a given time in the day. I am able to get the data `{ azimuth: -2.100262873246889, altitude: -0.01481415957435166 }` but not sure how to get the 3D coordinates out of it.

Here is my code:

```
import SunCalc from "suncalc";

const LAT = 68.148357;
const LNG = 9.996031;
const dateandtime = "2019-07-01T17:01:29.467Z";

var times = SunCalc.getTimes(new Date(dateandtime), LAT, LNG);
var sunrisePos = SunCalc.getPosition(times.sunrise, LAT, LNG);
```

Comment: Hi @Wahsh while an interesting question, I think it's beyond the scope of StackOverflow which deals with programming related stuff. Your problem is more akin to mathematics or physics than programming. Try posting it here https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi @Wahsh, Did you get any solution. I need the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = R * cos(ϕ) * sin(θ)
y = R * cos(ϕ) * cos(θ)
z = R * sin(ϕ)
```

Where R is the distance of the point from the origin, θ (the azimuth), and ϕ (the elevation).